# Given a sequence, how do I find the limit of the product/sum of all its terms?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

say I have $x_n$ such that

$\lim_{n\to \infty}$ $x_n$ $=$ $a$

What is:

$\lim_{n\to \infty}$   $\sum_{i=1}^n x_n$

And:

$\lim_{n\to \infty}$ $\prod_{i=1}^n x_n$

I know that the limit of a sum is the sum of the limits, similarly with products, but how exactly do I implement that here?
Like for instance $\lim_{n\to \infty}$ $x_1$ would just be $x_1$, and
$\lim_{n\to \infty}$ $x_n$ would just be $a$. So if you take the sum from left to right you'd get $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} x_n$ whereas if you take the sum from right to left you'd just get $\lim_{n\to \infty}$ $an$ which would just be infinity. Perhaps I'm missing something obvious, kindly help

Comment: If a series converges then the terms must go to $0$.  Thus, if $a\neq 0$ in your limit, the sum can not converge. However, even if $a=0$ the sum may diverge.

Comment: What about the product(if a ≠ 0)?

Comment: Well, the product should be compared to the sum of the logs.  So, now you want $a=1$.

Comment: All right, say a = 1. If the limit of the product is L, then taking logs we'd get ln(L) = ln($x_1$)+......+ln($x_n$). How would I evaluate that? Im guessing this is a beginner question but I'm really new to analysis

Comment: Oh, just knowing that the limit of terms is good tells us very little.  As I mentioned, it doesn't even imply that the expression (sum or product) exists, and it certainly doesn't help you at all with evaluating those expressions.

Answer (score 1):

The limit does not uniquely determine the sum or product of the sequence.

Consider the two sequence $x_n = 0$ and $y_n = 0$ if $n \ne 0$ and $y_1 = 1$. Then $\lim_n x_n = 0$, $\lim_n y_n = 0$, but $\lim_n \sum_1^n x_j = 0$ and $\lim_n \sum_1^n y_j = 1$.

Similarly set $a_n = 1$ and $b_n = 1$ if $n \ne 0$ and $b_1 = 0$. Then $\lim_n a_n = 1$ and $\lim_n b_n = 1$, but $\lim_n \prod_1^n a_j = 1$ and $\lim_n \prod_1^n b_j = 0$.

Comment: So what more would one need to uniquely determine the limit of the sum or product?

Comment: The actual values of each element of the sequence.